# Left Join 2 tables, return only records that appears on the 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I'm left joining 2 tables (`table1` and `table2`).

The 1st table contains unique `globalcid` of each record, 2nd table contains multiple occurrences of the same `globalcid`. Note: `globalcid` is the reference field of table2 to table1.

> table1

```
globalcid  / itemdesc
1          / item 1
2          / item 2
3          / item 3
4          / item 4
5          / item 5
```

> table2

```
globalcid    /  recordcid
1            / 1
1            / 2
2            / 1
3            / 1
3            / 2
3            / 3
5            / 1
```

I want a query to return only the records from [table1] with record in [table2] GROUP BY table2.globalcid but will return last record of each globalcid

In the example above it should return

```
globalcid  / itemdesc  / table2.globalcid
1          / item 1    / 2
2          / item 2    / 1
3          / item 3    / 3
5          / item 5    / 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    MAX(b.recordcid) AS maxcid
FROM 
    table1 a
INNER JOIN 
    table2 b ON a.globalcid = b.globalcid
GROUP BY 
    a.globalcid
```

If you're only concerned about the `recordcid` and do not need any other columns from that table, then this should be fine. However, if there are other columns in the table like such:

```
globalcid    /  recordcid   /  othercolumn 
------------------------------------------
1            / 1            /  bertrand
1            / 2            /  centipede
2            / 1            /  yarn
3            / 1            /  obviate
3            / 2            /  hyper
3            / 3            /  fish
5            / 1            /  larry
```

...then the `MAX()` value will not line up with its corresponding row data in `othercolumn`, and instead you must wrap the selection of the max in a subselect like so:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    c.recordcid,
    c.othercolumn
FROM
    table1 a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT globalcid, MAX(recordcid) AS maxcid
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY globalcid
    ) b ON a.globalcid = b.globalcid
INNER JOIN
    table2 c ON b.globalcid = c.globalcid AND b.maxcid = c.recordcid
```

Resulting in:

```
globalcid    /  itemdesc    /  recordcid   /  othercolumn 
---------------------------------------------------------
1            /  item1       / 2            /  centipede
2            /  item2       / 1            /  yarn
3            /  item3       / 3            /  fish
5            /  item5       / 1            /  larry
```

Comment: I need to include another field from [table2]

Comment: Great! Then you must use the second solution I posted and just replace `c.othercolumn` with the column you wish to select. Make sure to keep the alias `c` prepended to the column name. You also might want to adjust your table schema to include those columns as it will make a difference in solutions posted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using an *inner join* and an aggregation:

```
SELECT table1.globalcid, itemdesc, MAX(recordcid)
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.globalcid = table2.globalcid
GROUP BY table1.globalcid, itemdesc
```

The inner join excludes all records in *table2* that don't have a matching id in *table1*.  MAX / GROUP BY will pull out the max value of *recordid* for each *globalcid*.

Comment: This does not select the last record of each item, it selects the 1st one